# Error while compiling contracts: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle5'

Tags: web3js, hardhat

Below error occurs while compiling smart contracts through hardhat.

```
npx hardhat compile --show-stack-traces
```

An unexpected error occurred:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle5'
Require stack:
- /home/vasu/Desktop/Gravita-SmartContracts/hardhat.config.js
- /home/vasu/node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/config/config-loading.js
- /home/vasu/node_modules/hardhat/internal/cli/cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vasu/Desktop/Gravita-SmartContracts/hardhat.config.js:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/vasu/Desktop/Gravita-SmartContracts/hardhat.config.js',
    '/home/vasu/node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/config/config-loading.js',
    '/home/vasu/node_modules/hardhat/internal/cli/cli.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't imported the plugin for hardhat.
Go to your hardhat.config.js and use the following plugin.

`require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");`

Read the Hardhat documentation for more info on this.

if this doesn't work try to find the specific plugin your need, which in your case is ***'@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle5'***
Try importing this in your hardhat config file.

Comment: working but please look into this

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/149654/error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir-root-config-hardhat-nodejs please look this \