# Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.config/hardhat-nodejs'

Tags: web3js, javascript, hardhat

While compiling below errors occurs anyone please look into this

````
Learn more at https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/reference/solidity-support

An unexpected error occurred:

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.config/hardhat-nodejs'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1336:3)
    at Object.mkdirsSync (/home/vasu/Desktop/Gravita-SmartContracts/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/mkdirs-sync.js:31:9)
    at getConfigDirSync (/home/vasu/Desktop/Gravita-SmartContracts/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/util/global-dir.ts:22:6)
    at hasConsentedTelemetry (/home/vasu/Desktop/Gravita-SmartContracts/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/util/global-dir.ts:105:21)
    at main (/home/vasu/Desktop/Gravita-SmartContracts/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/cli.ts:203:70) {
  errno: -13,
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  code: 'EACCES',
  path: '/root/.config/hardhat-nodejs'
}```
````

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the filesystem permissions. It is quite strange for a node module trying to access the `/root` folder. You should ask the project developers to provide a README with instructions how to use it.